# The price doesn't show up with the regular code from WooCommerce in a related products list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

What I'm trying to do is show the price besides the title of the product in a related products list that is in the sidebar... but it doesn't work for some reason.

Yes, I have searched the StackOverflow archive and Google and found the obvious answer:

```
<?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
```

but this one doesn't work in my code structure:

```
<h4>Related products</h4>
   <ul class="prods-list">
     <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>
        <li>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank">
           <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' ); ?>
           <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
          /a>
          </li>
          <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
  </ul>
```

What am I doing wrong here? I tried adding that code after the title span, but it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to invoke a method from the Product class on a Post object. I can't tell for sure without seeing code before it, but it looks like the $products variable is set to an instance of WP_Query(). If that's the case, then you need to do two things:

1. Get an instance of a Product object using the current Post ID
2. Invoke the get_price_html() method on the Product object

You can write this more succinctly, but I'm going to lay it out piece by piece to explain what each thing does. Your code should look something like this:

```
<h4>Related products</h4>
  <ul class="prods-list">
    <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>
      <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank">
          <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' ); ?>
          <?php

            // Get the ID for the post object currently in context
            $this_post_id = get_the_ID();

            // Get an instance of the Product object for the product with this post ID
            $product = wc_get_product($this_post_id);

            // Get the price of this product - here is where you can 
            // finally use the function you were trying
            $price = $product->get_price_html();

          ?>
          <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>

          <?php
            // Now you can finally echo the price somewhere in your HTML:
            echo $price;
          ?>

        </a>
      </li>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot, Josh!

Comment: Awesome! Would you mind marking this as the accepted answer? It will help people who have a similar problem in the future :-)

Comment: Done. Thank you once again.

Comment: Thanks! Good luck with your dev.